# _Job data view and viewing dynamic subject lines, impossible?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dynamic, data-views

Logically speaking, I believe it's pretty much impossible for the `_Job` data view to be able to record VARYING subject lines (based on dynamic rules and whatnot) with the same `JobId` - correct assumption? In other words, there's a field called "`EmailSubject`" in the `_Job` data view and that obviously is a placeholder for simply one subject line per `JobId`.

My client's use case is this (and probably a lot of other clients' use cases as well): for a specific email, they have dynamic rules set up (much like inline AMPScript in the subject line field) to determine which subject line to display in the subscriber's email client. So one email could have one of many different subject lines, but it appears that the Job data view only records the "default" subject line.

I wanted to confirm this was intentional. I believe it is, and I was also wondering is there perhaps a way to be able to record the correct subject lines actually sent based on the rules in the subject line field?

Couple ideas I had were:

1. Break up the email send into separate "batches" (aka Jobs) with like subject lines.
2. Perhaps there's a weird, hidden system data view (I have no idea honestly) that supports what we're trying to do?

Comment: you would need to use a sendlog and capture the subjectline in a field within the subject line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you set your subject line using Ampscript (e.g. by placing `%%=v(@SubjectLine)=%%` in the subject line field of the email in Content Builder), you will not be able to view this information in any of the data views. What you are left with is creating a sendlog solution, and dump each personalised version of the subject line there during sendtime. Each record in the sendlog comes normally with a.o. JobID and SubscriberID fields, so you will need to add *SubjectLine* field there as well. This needs to have the same name as your Ampscript variable holding the subject, and will be populated for each recipient during send. You will then be able to lookup all the variations of the subject line by referencing the appropriate JobID in SQL Query within Automation Studio.